# is there any free rich text box that can add a video from youtube?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am searching for a rich text box like the ajax editor, where i can add an image or a video or smiles?

is there any free rich text for this one?

Comment: How, exactly, do you expect the video to be rendered/expressed in a text box?  Do you have a live example of what you're looking for?

Comment: I think the OP is looking for an in site WYSIWYG content editor that is capable of embedding youtube.

Comment: yes u can see the rad editor (telerik.)

Comment: like this one 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your absolute choice is [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) that met your need and here the [Demo URL](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

it will have support images and flash movies

Comment: yes i like this one ,but it's not free!!!

Comment: this is open source and free man :)

Comment: i wish it is , but see this http://ckeditor.com/license

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/download download first link, it is free, I am using free from many years

Comment: Depends on the licensing for the product where you're using it, I suppose.  Though, if you're creating a commercial product, you can't always demand free products.  Commercial begets commercial.

Answer (score 0):

Something like http://www.freetextbox.com/?

Comment: thank you , but this one can not add a video !!